# Can't create user for ceph dashboard

Tags: ceph

I'm trying to create a user for ceph dashboard with admin role. Version is Nautilus 14.2.19 and deployed with manuel installation.

I've installed dashboard module, installed all dependencies and enabled it. My dashboard is reachable from the monitor ip and default port of 8443.

When I run te command:

```
ceph dashboard ac-user-create <user> <pw> administrator
```

I get the following error:

```
Please specify the file containing the password/secret with "-i" option.
```

After digging for information about this it says there must be a file in bcrypt format. Is there a default created file for this? Or if it's needed to create one how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, it seems you just need to create a text file and write your password in it.

When you run the command like this:

```
ceph dashboard ac-user-create <user> -i /file/location administrator
```

It creates the user and applies the password in an encrypted format.